# The circus's Riley-Riddle

Tags: riddle

I am getting addicted to Riley's riddles:

> My prefix is one,
> My infix is cold.
> My suffix is vehicle,
> I really am single

Hint:

> It already has a hint! Didn't you see the title?;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Unicycle

My prefix is one,

> **Uni** is a prefix meaning "one"

My infix is cold.

> **Icy**

My suffix is vehicle,

> **Cycle**

I really am single

> A unicycle has just one wheel.

Title

> Unicycle acts are often performed at the circus

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I'm onto you hexomino, I know you're an alien.